# [JWNavigationController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7faf61425ef0'

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my old project i has used JWNavigationController for slider menu.in iPHONE6,iPHONE7 device working proper but when i am run app in iphonex, Xr ,Xs Max than app is crashed.i have set exception breakpoint but can not find crash line please help me.

Here is my crash log

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[JWNavigationController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7faf61425ef0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000112fa66fb __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011254aac5 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000112fc4ab4 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   UIKitCore                           0x00000001205fdc3d -[UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 287
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000112fab443 ___forwarding___ + 1443
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000112fad238 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    6   UIKitCore                           0x0000000120a741a1 -[UIView _setSafeAreaInsets:updateSubviewsDuringNextLayoutPass:] + 261
    7   UIKitCore                           0x0000000120a742d9 -[UIView setSafeAreaInsets:] + 75
    8   UIKitCore                           0x000000011ffc3592 -[UIViewController _updateViewSafeAreaInsetsAndEagerlyUpdateContentScrollView:] + 124
    9   UIKitCore                           0x000000011ffc3df2 -[UIViewController _setContentOverlayInsets:andLeftMargin:rightMargin:] + 940
    10  UIKitCore                           0x000000011ffc5f64 __121-[UIViewController __updateContentOverlayInsetsWithOurRect:inBoundsOfAncestorViewController:viaImmediateChildOfAncestor:]_block_invoke + 497
    11  UIKitCore                           0x000000011ffc5d2d -[UIViewController __updateContentOverlayInsetsWithOurRect:inBoundsOfAncestorViewController:viaImmediateChildOfAncestor:] + 3915
    12  UIKitCore                           0x000000011ffc4a35 -[UIViewController _updateContentOverlayInsetsFromParentIfNecessary] + 587
    13  UIKitCore                           0x000000011ffc4229 -[UIViewController _updateContentOverlayInsetsForSelfAndChildren] + 229
    14  UIKitCore                           0x000000011ffd1dc9 -[UIViewController _updateLayoutForStatusBarAndInterfaceOrientation] + 954
    15  UIKitCore                           0x000000011ffd2081 -[UIViewController _updateLayoutForStatusBarAndInterfaceOrientation] + 1650
    16  UIKitCore                           0x000000011ffd7a8d -[UIViewController viewDidMoveToWindow:shouldAppearOrDisappear:] + 1184
    17  UIKitCore                           0x0000000120a96962 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 1414
    18  UIKitCore                           0x0000000120a894ee __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 151
    19  UIKitCore                           0x0000000120a893cd -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 795
    20  UIKitCore                           0x0000000120a9963d -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1948
    21  UIKitCore                           0x0000000120a5c749 -[UITransitionView transition:fromView:toView:removeFromView:] + 1540
    22  UIKitCore                           0x000000011fff83f2 -[UIViewControllerBuiltinTransitionViewAnimator animateTransition:] + 2080
    23  UIKitCore                           0x000000011feef985 __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke + 3088
    24  UIKitCore                           0x00000001205dccc9 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 318
    25  UIKitCore                           0x00000001205cc199 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 358
    26  UIKitCore                           0x00000001205f932b _afterCACommitHandler + 124
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000112f0d0f7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000112f075be __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 430
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000112f07c31 __CFRunLoopRun + 1505
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000112f07302 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 626
    31  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000116fbb2fe GSEventRunModal + 65
    32  UIKitCore                           0x00000001205d1ba2 UIApplicationMain + 140
    33  Audi                                0x000000010f8c9b40 main + 112
    34  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001148d4541 start + 1
    35  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: I already search the name `JWNavigationController` but don't have any result. Give me the lib you're using

Comment: JWSlideMenuViewController library pls check

Comment: I've just clone this code and run demo, it still work in iPhoneX, Xr, Xs Max. Give me more about your situation, example: which type of rootVC? Is that present any viewcontroller before crash? Which ViewController, NavigationController passed through before go to Menu Page, ...

Comment: If no one helps you out in the coming hours, perhaps you want to consider sharing a sample project that reproduces this issue.